# CSS two elements auto-height inside one block

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to put two blocks into one fixed-height block to create the following layout:

------------------------

UL (initial height=0),

grows on element add until maximum height reached

scroll should be added after max height is reached

------------------------

DIV (initial height=100% of parent)

decreases until min height is reached

------------------------

HTML part of the layout:

```
<div style="height:100px">
  <ul style="max-height:70px;height:auto;overflow:auto"></ul>
  <div style="min-height:30px;height:auto">
    <span>TEST CONTENT</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post what you've tried (maybe including a link to an http://jsfiddle.net demo too)?

Comment: Just to clarify: the ul and div are children of the same fixed height block, are not children of one another, and max-height of ul + min-height of div = fixed height of parent?

Comment: I meant, markup and css, not more description of the css. *Show us* what you're doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really can't do this cleanly with just CSS.  I'd suggest using a bit of jQuery for this where you just query the height of both at any given time, figure out which is taller, and then set the other element to match

Comment: Even simpler, I could just recalculate height of the bottom element by subtracting top element's height.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that the `DIV`'s properties are entirely clear. Note, this is not an answer (yet), just too long to put into a comment.

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="list">
    <ul></ul>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <span>TEST CONTENT</span>
  </div>
</div>

#container {
    height: 100px;
    background: grey;
}
#list {
    max-height: 70px;
    overflow: auto;
    background: #ddf;
}
#content {
    min-height: 30px;
    height: auto;
    background: #fdf;
}

// For testing
setInterval(function(){
    $('ul').append('<li>Test</li>');
},3000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/V8yuN/

Now, if you want the `DIV#content` to at first take up the entire height, but then shrink as the `DIV#list UL` grows, what is it you're trying to accomplish with `DIV#content`? Note, I put the `UL` within a `DIV`.

Now, the above fiddle demonstrates in a way what you're describing (the `DIV#content` gets pushed to the bottom). The question I have is, what does the `height` of the `DIV#content` matter in your design?

**EDIT**

Note, if you make the `#container` `overflow: hidden` and make the `#content`'s `height: 100%`, it would appear as if the `#container` is shrinking.

```
#container {
    height: 100px;
    background: grey;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#list {
    max-height: 70px;
    overflow: auto;
    background: #ddf;
}
#content {
    height: 100%;
    background: #fdf;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/V8yuN/2

I have no idea, though, if that would cause your design to break, if the `#content`'s actual content needs to display (for instance, if it is changed dynamically).

**EDIT 2**

The following accomplishes everything but the `vertical-align` of the `#content` text:

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="push">
    <div id="list">
      <ul></ul>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
      <div class="border-top"></div>
      <div id="content-inner">
        <span>TEST CONTENT</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="border-bottom"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container {
    height: 100px;
    background: grey;
}
#push {
    height: 95px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#list {
    max-height: 70px;
    overflow: auto;
    background: #ddf;
}
#content-inner {
    min-height: 100px;
    background: #dfd;
    margin: 0;
    border-left: 5px solid #fdf;
    border-right: 5px solid #fdf;
}
.border-top {
    background: #fdf;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    height: 5px;
}
.border-bottom {
    background: #fdf;
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    height: 5px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/V8yuN/6/

Comment: Yes, I've understood your idea with ``overflow:hidden``, but unfortunately that's not my case(. I have a border and rounded-corners on this element so they just get invisible.

Comment: You might then want to put the border and rounded corners on another element. Can you edit the fiddle and add the css you're describing?

Comment: The borders look good, thanks, but note also that I would like to have text in the middle of the block. May be I should give JavaScript a try... didn't know that it could be such hard in CSS :)

Comment: Oh, right. Yes, Javascript (or jQuery, if you're using it) would perhaps be simpler if you're already using it.

Comment: Keep in mind, what you're trying to do goes against what CSS typically does, which is that you're trying to *remove* (recalculate) height following a change to an element above that element. To make it work in CSS, you have to find a way to mimic that (for instance, with the technique I demonstrated). There may be a CSS master who can conjure CSS that works that way, but just thinking about it, I don't think it's possible without changing the markup, and much simpler with JS if you want the `vertical-align` to work.

Comment: @dragoon - I added the last fiddle, which I believe answers the actual question itself (notwithstanding the `vertical-align` issue, which is a special case and not part of the actual question itself). Please mark it as the answer if you think it appropriate; you may consider opening another question dealing with the `vertical-align` issue. `:)`

Comment: Thanks for the help Jared, I've ended up with a really simple JavaScript, DA. was the first to suggest, +1 to you anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your html looks like this:

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="top">
    </div>
    <div id="bottom">
    </div>
</div>
```

then your CSS could look like this, with #wrap height set, and a min-height for the bottom.
Mind the h`eight 100% !important`.

```
#wrap{
    height: 400px;
    background: #ccc;
}
#top{
    //height: 200px; for testing 
    background: #f0f;
}
#bottom{
    height: 100% !important;
    min-height: 200px;
    overflow: scroll;
    background: #000;
}
```

is that kind of what you're searching for?

Would help though if you could post the stuff you've already done.

Comment: This only works when you manually set the height of the top element I believe, but I add elements to my ``ul`` dynamically. I could  use javascript of course, but trying to find a pure CSS solution.

Comment: Just test it; when you set the top height to auto it should work I guess.

Comment: Just tested, bottom element gets pushed down and placed below the parent's bottom.

Comment: Could be. As stated before, a real css solutions isn't available. This is the best you can do with Css. jQuery on the other hand, has perfect solutions